# How to get Captions for videos using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

Is possible to retrieve (get) captions for a YouTube video (not owned by the user) from the YouTube API?

Comment: Anything displayable are retrievable (not sure whether directly usable, though). Probably not via the Youtube API, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @nhahtdh even commentary balloons?

Comment: Do you mean annotations?

Answer (score 4):

- In v2, you can access only your videos captions.
- In v3, there is no support for captions yet, but will be supported soon.

It's a Terms of Service issue, not to provide these captions.

Comment: Hello Ibrahim, do you have any roadmap. When captions for v3 will be available? How long we need to wait it?