# Getting caption from Youtube URL

Tags: youtube-api

How to get captions from a youtube URL using app-script?

It has service in v2 - https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions.
It is deprecated officially.

How to do the same in Youtube API v3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Captions for videos using YouTube API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848333/how-to-get-captions-for-videos-using-youtube-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Captions are not currently exposed via the V3 api. The official word from the YouTube API team is that they will get this functionality available before v2 is removed (April 20th, 2015 is the earliest that might happen per the deprecation policy, but it could be later as well).

Here's a blog post that details it more fully:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3.html